# vue-pdf demo not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm looking to embed PDF files in my `vue.js 2` web app. It looks like the best option is to use [vue-pdf](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf). I have the following two questions:

1. The [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fossfiddler/5k4ptmqg/145/) on the readme.md doesn't appear to be working. Is this true for everyone or just me?
2. Are there better options for rendering PDF's within my web app?

Comment: Except for the broken demo, do you experiment other issues using `vue-pdf` ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been marked as an issue [on github](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf/issues/78). Someone commented that adding

> window.PDFJS = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

to the line above workerSrc and fixing the pdf file link would make the demo work again. The creator has yet to accept this workaround.